# Screen height doesn't match actual screen height

Tags: java, android

**Solved:**

As Zoltán wrote I didn't take the statusbar and titlebar into consideration (They're both 25 in height)

I used the following code in my onClickListener method inside my Activity and forwarded the results to my Service class and printed it out there:

```
Rect rectgle = new Rect();
Window window = getWindow();
window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
int StatusBarHeight = rectgle.top;
int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
int TitleBarHeight = contentViewTop - StatusBarHeight;

serviceIntent.putExtra("Titlebarheight", Integer.toString(TitleBarHeight));
serviceIntent.putExtra("Statusbarheight", Integer.toString(StatusBarHeight));
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am trying to set the layout height of my ImageView in my **main.xml**, but when I set the layout_height to 270dp (or px) it fills up the whole screen from top to bottom, but my screen size is actually 320x240 (HTC magic - Android 1.5) - So it SHOULDN'T fill up the screen from top to bottom!

Code inside Activity:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Log.i("Screen height", Integer.toString(display.getHeight())); // Returns 320
Log.i("Screen width", Integer.toString(display.getWidth())); // Returns 240
```

Code inside main.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bitmapImageView"
    android:layout_height="270dp" // Fills up the whole screen from top to bottom
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Example when using 270 as layout height:

[image]

Example when using 240 as layout height:

[image]

Comment: dp and px are NOT the same unit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: I know they're NOT the same unit, but I just stated that I tried them both.

Comment: You want to do all UI Design  dynamically inside Activity or in XML?

Comment: Partly inside the Activity, but mostly in XML

Comment: Are you trying to make a full screen activity? By default an activity is not full screen and your layout xml is actually contained inside of a ViewGroup that is provided by Android to give you the title bar.

Comment: @Qberticus

That helps! How do I "subtract" the titlebar ViewGroup that fills up the top of the screen, when getting screen sizes?

Comment: If you want a view to fill up the entire vertical space use `fill_parent`. You don't have to try to calculate it manually. If you want a full screen activity, I edited my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the status bar and the title bar of your application seems to be about the same as the width of your `ImageView`, which is 50px judging from your XML.

So then 50px + 270px = 320px, which is the total height of your screen (including the status and title bar).

Answer (score 2):

See: [Screen Resolution of android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815380/screen-resolution-of-android) and
[scale-independent pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289458/scale-independent-pixel)

Basically, a dp (display-independent pixel) is not the same size on all displays. At your resolution 1dp =~ .75px

To do a full screen activity see: [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Specifically, set: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in the android manifest for that activity.

Comment: Thx. But I'm not interested in doing a full-screen Activity, I just need to retrieve the visible Activity size.